# why the need for cin.unget() in this context, C++?

Tags: c++, cin

I'm relatively new to programming and i was experimenting with some codes from Bjarne's book on principles and practice using C++.

I would like to know why is there the need for `cin.unget()` when the input is not an integer whereas `cin.unget()` is not needed when the input is an integer?

Do note that this code is not perfect as the author is merely attempting to illustrate some pointers on users' input and output. The code is as follows:

```
void skip_to_int()
{
    if (cin.fail()){
        cin.clear();
        for (char ch; cin>>ch; ) { // throw away non-digits
            if (isdigit(ch) || ch=='-') {
                cin.unget();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    error("no input");
}

int main(){
    cout << "Please enter an integer in the range 1 to 10(inclusive):\n";
    int n = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (cin>>n) { // we got an integer; now check it
            if (1<=n && n<=10) break;
            cout << "Sorry " << n
            << " is not in the [1:10] range; please try again\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Sorry, that was not a number; please try again\n";
            skip_to_int(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's scanning through your input stream to find digits or `-` which is part of a negative digit presumably. This is a rather curious way of stripping off things like spaces or tabs.

The reason for `unget()` is to push that character back into the stream so it can be parsed later with `cin>>n`. If you consumed it and threw it away it wouldn't be available at that point.